# How to Type a deep object destructuring in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typing, destructuring, google-chrome-storage

I'm trying to Type a deep object destructuring in Typescript and I have searched a whole bunch but found nothing that quite answers my question, so I thought I'd ask it.

I have something *like* this in my class:

```
public Example(
  key1: string,
  key2: string,
  val: string,
  callback: (list: string[]) => void
): void
{
  chrome.storage.sync.get(
    ({
      [key1]: list1,
      [key2]: list2
    }) => {
      list1.includes(val)
        ? callback(list1.filter(i => i !== val))
        : callback(list2)
    }
  );
}
```

I haven't found a way to Type `list1` and `list2` (as `string[]`) and they get set as `any` which is no use to me when trying to use array functions. I've found examples of how to Type if the *key* is known (`{ key }: { key: string[] }`) but not for my situation. I also can't create a Type as the LHS is non-static.

My example is altered somewhat but contains everything needed to get my question across.

In case it's needed, the `chrome.d.ts` I have states:

```
/**
 * Gets one or more items from storage.
 * @param callback Callback with storage items, or on failure (in which case runtime.lastError will be set).
 * Parameter items: Object with items in their key-value mappings.
 */
get(callback: (items: { [key: string]: any }) => void): void;
```

I'm sure it's probably really simple and I've just not found anything; that being said, this question might make it easier for other people to find in future so it'd be win-win if solved.

I appreciate all and any help.

---

EDIT: I guess I'm also looking for the case where it's not *just* `string[]` that is returned. What if you have a whole bunch of data that were all different types?

Answer (score 2):

Use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to correct the third-party types:

**`chrome.d.ts`**

```
import {} from 'chrome';

declare namespace chrome.storage {
  export interface StorageArea {
    get(callback: (items: { [key: string]: string[] }) => void): void;
  }
}
```

In case you were wondering, the empty import statement on the top of the file is required for the file to be treated as *module augmentation* instead of its definition.

The best thing about it? If you're not happy with `string[]` there, you can augment it in some other way. You can also make `get` generic.

Comment: What if you have a whole bunch of data that were all different types and not just string[]? This is really good to know though.

Comment: Then you add another overload. It's perfectly fine to have many of them. I don't know the details of your problem, but if you look into the built-in overloaded methods (like `Array.prototype.filter`) you will see how it's done.

Comment: So if I want to destructure an `any` with two variables, one is a `string[]` and the second is a `number`, this is possible? I'm under the impression that using declaration merging I could destructure to be all `string[]` or all `number` but not both (or would I need to do `string[]|number`)?

Answer (score 1):

So you are getting type `any` because the `get` function has it like that.

Hence you could do this:

```
type MyGet = (callback: (items: {[key: string]: string[]}) => void) => void

// inside the Example method
(chrome.storage.sync.get as MyGet)(
          ({
            [key1]: list1,
            [key2]: list2
          }) => {
            list1.includes(val)
              ? callback(list1.filter(i => i != val))
              : callback(list2)
          }
        );
```

The other and the better approach in case if there is a possibility to encounter other types, is to use type guards:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(
          ({
            [key1]: list1,
            [key2]: list2
          }) => {

            if(Array.isArray(list1)) {
              list1.includes(val)
                ? callback(list1.filter(i => i != val))
                : callback(list2)
            }
          }
        );
```

This is OK in terms of type safety, because narrowing down type `any` to `string[]` should be considered OK.

Comment: What if you have a whole bunch of data that were all different types and not just `string[]`?

Comment: @PhilB. Since you are dealing with a 3rd party library which defines the type as `any` there is hardly anything better you can do than manually typing your data *or* leaving it `any`, probably also adding @ts-ignore or type assertions here and there (but the best way is using [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)).

Comment: Yeah I get you. I'm currently settling for `(list1 as string[])` but it feels like there _should_ be a way to write it nicely. Maybe I can push it into a Type in a private method now it's retrieved and clean up some of that complexity. Thanks though.

Comment: @PhilB. I've updated my answer. The nice and runtime-reliable way is to use type guards.

Comment: @PhilB. Don't forget your promised appreciation! Of course if there is no other answers suggesting a better way. On SO you are supposed to appreciate by upvoting and/or selecting the most useful answer.